# Latex how to call subsubsections in text

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, best-practices

I am writing a large text using Latex, where I use chapters, sections, subsections, subsubsections and paragraphs. My problem is that I would like to write, in my text, something like "this is described in the following subsubseciton", but for obvious reasons I am reluctant to use the word "subsection" in the text, so I was wondering if that is the right word to use (I cannot use words as section, subsection, paragraph and chapter because they are already used somewhere else).

Comment: I think using "subsection" in the text is perfectly OK.

Comment: I agree that *subsection* is ok, but i fail to see the TeXnical part of the question.

Comment: One could use the sectioning symbol, `\S`, and say "in `S\ref{<subsubseclabel>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `cleveref` package and code `\cref{<subsubsectionlabel>}`, which will print as `Section x.y.z`. The difference between the various sectioning levels is reflected in the numbering.

You also can customise the string which will appear as the subsubsection name with

```
\crefname{subsubsection}{\S}{\S}
\Crefname{subsubsection}{\S}{\S}
```

These can go either  in your preamble or in a `cleveref.cfg` file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I think this is the solution that best suits my problem, I will try to do as you suggest me

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any of the sectioning titles, I think it would be OK for you to just print the section number, including the other levels. It would not be immediate as seeing the word, but the numbering would still be unambiguous. However keep in mind that `\paragraph` doesn't carry a number by default, so referring to this will still show the `\subsubsection` number where it's located.

Latex supports this by default, by doing for example:

```
\subsubsection{My subsubsection}\label{subsubsec}
```

And then referring to it in the text normally, e.g. `As showed in \ref{subsubsec}`. If this is the first of all the document, for example, you'll see `As showed in 1.1.1` in the resulting PDF.

Comment: Also `As showed in section~\ref{subsubsec}`, because the numbering immediately points to the level.

Comment: Thank you I think this suggestion may be very elegant, even if I am more tempted to use the _crefname_ package proposed by Bernard this is also an excellent solution that I will keep in mind for the future. Thank you a lot.